# Receiving variables from Automator as a String

Tags: python, automator

I have an Automator script that gets the comments from the current song. I need to pass those comments to Python for further processing, however, when I print the results in python, my results are not the actual comments from the song. I have verified that my Automator variable has the correct comments, but it does not make it to python. [image]

when I print the variable in python, i get the following:

`'-c','\n'`

Am i missing something to properly receive the variable in python?

UPDATE:

[image: updated_script]

Comment: Your `Run Shell Script` (actually Python) action is set to pass input to stdin rather than as arguments. I can't test right now, but this might be causing the problem. BTW, is there any reason you set a variable and then immediately get it, rather than just passing the comments straight from the `Run Applescript` action to `Run Shell Script`?

Comment: Gordon, I have implemented both of your suggestions, thanks. Lastly, is there any way to run Python 3.7 vs python2?

Comment: I don't know. [This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/146462/how-can-i-add-shells-to-the-list-in-run-shell-script-in-the-automator#146840) suggests adding other "shells" to /System/Library/Automator/Run Shell Script.action/Contents/Resources/Shells.plist, but that file's now protected by System Integrity Protection, so it's tricky to change. There *should* be an easier way, I just don't know of one.